# OpenVPN: failed running command (--up/--down) could not execute external program

Tags: openvpn

I am trying to establish a VPN connecting using protonVPN.

I set up everything but I am getting the following error:

[image: OpenVPN output]

What is the reason of the following error:

`Warning: Failed running command (--up/--down) could not execute external program`

Seems everything is running fine but the `--up/--down` !

Sorry I couldn't copy the text as I am booting my board through hdmi

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with OpenVPN. I tried to establish connection when already have it on second machine.
Check maybe someone use your credentials.